# Xamarin.Forms - Android/iOS : Push notification not working if app is killed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I have used `https://github.com/CrossGeeks/PushNotificationPlugin` for push notifications in my xamarin.forms application.

The major issue I am facing currently is Notifications not arriving in device once the app is closed. Here is how the push notifications working:

- it works if app is in foreground or background,
- if kill app and then send notification it not works
- if you again open app and it's again either in background or foreground notifications not works

```css
So it works only first time when app is installed in device and it's in 
either Foreground or background.
```

### Anyone know how to handle this issue?

---

I have initialised plugin in both Android and iOS also setup all required things.

Version of packages I have used:

- Xamarin.Forms - 4.7.0.968
- Plugin.PushNotification - 1.3.0

#### 1 Code in App.xaml.cs OnStartMethod

```cs
CrossPushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
{
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
    {
        DeviceToken = p.Token;
    }
};

CrossPushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += async (s, p) =>
{
    //Logic to handle arrived notification 
};

CrossPushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += async (s, p) =>
{
    //Notification tap handler code here
};

CrossPushNotification.Current.OnNotificationDeleted += (s, p) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Dismissed");
};
```

---

#### 2 Android Main Application class

```cs
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            //Change for your default notification channel id here
            PushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "DefaultChannel";

            //Change for your default notification channel name here
            PushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";
        }

        //If debug you should reset the token each time.
#if DEBUG
        PushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
#else

        PushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, false);
#endif

        //PushNotificationManager.IconResource = Resource.Drawable.icon;

        //Handle notification when app is closed here
        CrossPushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
        {
                
        };
    }
}
```

---

#### 3 Android: MainActivity class

```cs
protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)        
{
    LoadApplication(new App());
    PushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);
}
```

Comment: I test this sample, it works fine when app is background or foreground. It also works fine when app close and open again.

Comment: Have you test it in release mode? first kill your app from background and then without open it try to send notification, it will not work. Again open it and then try to send notification it not works. I have test this in android Lollipop 5.0 device. Share your sample here. Your nuget's versions?

Comment: I change it in Release mode, then I test it in Emulator 9.0, first I kill my app from background, then send notification,  I will get this message from statusbar. Then opening app, send notification, I also get it.

Comment: how you are sending test notifications?

Comment: I send notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging, you can take a [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging)

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I have fixed this issue, my android device token is keep getting null while app call onstart method. That causes the problem

Comment: Ok, glad to hear this.

Comment: @Divyesh_08 Please.. please.... share what you did... I am stuck. I don't know why, It just doesn't work when App is Closed. No notifications come out.